# add circle surounding the bullet of llist style

Tags: html, css

Can someone teach me how to center this circle position surounding the bullet list style. 
I have done some, but its not good enough

```css
.poe li {
  list-style: none;
 
}
.poe li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: black;

}
.poe:hover .anime,
.poe:hover ~ .anime {
    color: #fff;
   
         -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform: scale(0.5);
}
 
.anime {
 margin-left:-23px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:thin solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>1. HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>2. HOVER ME</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.poe li` should be `li.poe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made few changes to your CSS and the added a [demo](https://codepen.io/AravinthAro/pen/LYVbKwZ) here.
Note I have removed some of your CSS and added few styles which I usually add for better finishing. Remove them if you want it.

```
    li.poe{
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
}
li.poe:before {
  content: "•";
  color: black;
  position:absolute;
  left:-15px;
}
.poe:hover .anime,
.poe:hover ~ .anime {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.anime {
    height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:thin solid black;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  left:-21px;
}
```

Comment: all these replyies are amazing, but i have to choose only one.

Answer (score 1):

`.poe`is the `li`element so change `.poe li` to `li.poe` then use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
.poe {
  list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.poe:before,
.poe:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute; 
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;/*width/2 and height/2*/
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all .3s ease 
}
.poe:before{
  background-color: black;
}
.poe:after{
  transform: scale(4)
}
.poe:hover {
  cursor: pointer
} 
.poe:hover:after{
  transform: scale(0)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>1. HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>2. HOVER ME</li>
</ul>
```

or

```css
.poe {
  list-style: none;
   position: relative
}
.poe:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
.poe:before,
.poe:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute; 
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;/*width/2 and height/2*/
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all .1s ease 
}
.poe:before{
  background-color: black;
}
 
.poe:hover:after{
  transform: scale(2.2,2.2)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>1. HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="poe"><span id="anime" class="anime"></span>2. HOVER ME</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments `.poe li` should be `li.poe`

I'm nout 100% sure what you are after but this might help:

```css
li.poe {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
li.poe:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -17px;
}
.poe:hover .anime {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
 
.anime {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -23px;
 height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:thin solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="poe"><span class="anime"></span>1. HOVER ME</li>
  <li class="poe"><span class="anime"></span>2. HOVER ME</li>
</ul>
```